# ros1_bridge package build warning

Tags: ros2, roscpp, ros1

As I want to use a ros1 driver node in my ros2 environment, I need to use the ros1_bridge package.
I am using ros1 noetic and ros2 foxy on Ubuntu 20.04
After I have cloned it from git hub, I have built the package and have a warning that: **failed to find ROS 1 roscpp, skipping...**

AI rechecked the roscpp package in ros1, it is successfully installed at the correct path. I have also sourced the environment for both my ros1 noetic and ros2 foxy in separated terminal, I rebuild the package again but still the same warning (see picture). I would really appreciate if someone can point out what could be the problem here and what I possibly miss out since its my first ros2 project. Thank you in advance :D
[image]